# r - turn off automatic ordering of linestrings when applying sf::st_intersection

Tags: r, intersection, linestring, sf, order

This question is about how while using `sf::st_intersection` on a `LINESTRING` and a set of `POLYGON`s to get several `LINESTRING`s in the **CORRECT** order. `sf::st_intersection` automatically orders the newly created `LINESTRING`s based on the names of the `POLYGON`s you have. To demonstrate this behavior is the following example:

```
# sample data for linestring
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(2,2),
  lon = c(4,9),
  lat = c(9,5)
)

df <- df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# function to create set of polygons
create_grid <- function(lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax, no_squares) {
  # a matrix defines the bounding box as required by st_make_grid()
  globe_bb <- matrix(c(lonmin,  latmax,
                   lonmax,  latmax,
                   lonmax, latmin,
                   lonmin, latmin,
                   lonmin,  latmax), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) %>%
  list() %>% 
  st_polygon() %>% 
  st_sfc(., crs = 4236)

grid <- st_make_grid(globe_bb, n = c(no_squares, no_squares),
                   crs = 4326, what = 'polygons')  %>%
  st_sf('geometry' = ., data.frame('ID' = 1:length(.)))
}
grid <- create_grid(0, 10, 1, 10, 4) %>% st_transform(4326)

# applying `sf::st_intersection` to linestring (df) and set of polygons (grid)
df_in <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% st_intersection(grid)
```

the current and expected output are explained in the following image:

[image]

Based on where the original `LINESTRING` starts and ends the order of the newly created `LINESTRING`s is not correct since it is ordered by the names of the `POLYGON`s.

Is there a way to set an argument in `sf::st_intersection` to turn off ordering by names of polygons by default, or is there maybe another approach to this issue ?

Comment: I don't think so, these structures get completely decomposed in the underlying libs and there's no control over it - it will come out in the order that the algorithm rebuilds the features. Simple features pointedly does not provide identity for sub-feature elements, and most tools that use the standard work around this in their own ways.

Comment: @mdsumner maybe there is a way to get the right sequence and reorder the rows afterwards ?

Comment: If you `st_intersection(df_in)` you'll see four POINT geometries which are the intersections of the line segments. Using the `origins` column you can pull out the line segment rows and then with a bit of graph theory work out the order... I'm not sure this is the best way to do it so I've not worked it through yet...

Comment: Yep, it's possible - I think @Spacedman is the world expert on it actually!  I find it hard and unworkable usually but am still keen to find ways

Comment: I'm not sure its even guaranteed that the line segments will be in the same direction as the original source line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function takes a data frame of line segments that, when connected, form a continuous chain. This is not tested for and it will fail if this isn't true.

```
library(igraph) # for connecting the points

reorder_segments <- function(src, parts){

    joints = st_intersection(parts)
    joints = joints[st_is(joints,"POINT"),]
    jgraph = igraph::graph_from_edgelist(do.call(rbind, joints$origins), directed=FALSE)

    ends = which(igraph::degree(jgraph) == 1)

    sps = igraph::shortest_paths(jgraph, ends[1], ends[2])

    path = sps$vpath[[1]]
    return(parts[path,])
}
```

Here's a helpful function for plotting the order of line segments in a data frame:

```
show_order <- function(lines,...){
    plot(st_geometry(lines))
    pts = st_coordinates(st_centroid(lines))
    text(pts[,1],pts[,2], 1:nrow(lines),...)
}
```

If you plot your data like this you'll see the order as in your image:

```
show_order(df_in,cex=3)
```

but then...

```
rs = reorder_segments(df, df_in)
show_order(rs,cex=3)
```

will show it in the new order - 1,2,3,4,5. There is a problem in that it can be in reverse order - 5,4,3,2,1. This could be tested for by overlaying the segments with the first point of the original data to see which is the first one. Left as an exercise....